# Why my EPUB background is black?

Tags: epub

I converted .docx file to .htm and convert it to .epub in Calibre. When i view it, the background color is black. How to change it?
I tried change the css background color but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: When you view it where? If you're using Calibre's viewer, you need to change the background color in the viewer preferences.

Comment: I view it using Calibre's viewer and tried it too on my android phone using ReadEra and it is still black

Comment: I tried change it. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I changed the viewer preferences and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Select an epub, press V (or View button); black on black, edge-to-edge.
I would try changing viewer preferences, but that's a Button (on the [Ctrl-F11] control menu - no keyboard shortcut for viewer pref's?) and it's _all_ also black on black... Now what?